# Is `*--p` actually legal(well formed) in C++03

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, language-lawyer, c++03

I'm wondering about this sample piece of code:

```
int main()
{
   char *p ;
   char arr[100] = "Hello";
   if ((p=arr)[0] == 'H') // do stuffs
}
```

Is this code actually well formed in C++03?

My argument is that the side effect of `=` is completed only after the next sequence point and since we are accessing the result of `p=arr` the code might not be well formed, there is no ordering between `=` and `[]` operations.

Am I correct?

The behavior  is well defined in C and in C++11. This code is actually derived from MySQL.

Comment: The code in the title doesn't appear in the code sample you've given.

Comment: Is `( (a=b) + x)` well-defined? If it is well-defined, then `(p=arr)[0]` would be well-defined as well, for it is equivalent to `*((p=arr) + 0)`

Comment: @Prasoon: According to your argument, `int x = ++i + n` invokes UB? Because according to you, the reason should be : the side effect of `++` is completed only after the next sequence point and since we are accessing the result of `++i` the code might not be well formed. Is it?

Comment: @Nawaz : you seemed to have agreed with me last night, didn't you?

Comment: ¤ The easy way to decide is to consider **idioms** such as `while( (c = getchar()) != EOF )`. That just has to be well-defined, since it's used so much. Case closed. Of course the C++03 standard's "after the assignment has taken place" is open for interpretation: it can mean that no matter the evaluation order, the stored value will be the result, or it can mean that the stored value is only available after the assignment. But the idiom argument clinches what the intended meaning must have been. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Prasoon: people with working score-filters will probably not have seen your "debate" with Leigh in clc++. That's because Leigh is notorious for trolling and for keeping trolling threads alive (and of course accusing everyone else of doing what he's doing). However, after a machine crash I chose to not reinstate the old kill files, so I've seen that discussion. I chose not to intervene because even if Leigh seemed to be right (about at least some things) this time, any comment, even supporting him against you, would probably be attacked. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: Actually there is no such thing as *permanently* "agree" (or "disagree") for me. I'm no Linus Towards, means I do change my opinion based on the information I get as the time passes, and that happened even last night: if you remember, I first disagreed with you, and then agreed, then I said "I don't have much knowledge about the subject, quoting one counter argument taken from the discussion at comp.lang.c++. :D

Comment: Isn't this an answer? http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/20e84b2dc5503b97

Comment: @wilhelmtell : The context is C++11 in that post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Of course it's well-defined.

It doesn't matter when the assignment `p=arr` takes place.  You aren't evaluating `p[0]`, you're subscripting the result of `(p=arr)`, which is the pointer value which is being stored into `p`.  Whether or not it's been stored yet doesn't change the value, and the value is known irrespective of whether `p` has been modified yet.

Similarly, in `*--p`, there's no undefined behavior.  There'd only be undefined behavior if the same variable was accessed twice, including at least one write, between sequence points.  But `p` is only accessed once, as part of `--p`.  It isn't read again (`*p`), the dereferencing operator is applied to the result of `--p` which is a well-defined pointer value.

Now, this would be undefined behavior:

```
void* a;
void* p = &a;
reinterpret_cast<void**>(p = &p)[0] = 0;
```

as would

```
int *pi = new int[5];
int i = **&++pi;
```

---

It should be clear that the result of a preincrement is not a read unordered with the write, because to assert that there is a race is to assert that `++p` can never be used as an rvalue, in which case it must stand alone between sequence points, and post-increment could be used instead.  There would be no advantage to having both pre-increment and post-increment in the language.

Comment: To any future readers, please see this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118996/where-did-all-the-comments-go-on-is-p-actually-legalwell-formed-in-c03

Comment: Also, a transcript of the deleted comments can be found here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/f4rIE.png